# Navigation Menu in the center

Tags: html, css, navbar

I want my navigation menu in the center i tried the methods which are posted in another similar question but not worked for me.. here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/suZR3/)

here is the code
HTML:

```
<div id="nav">

<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
    #nav {
    background:#111212;
    width: 100%;
    height:55px;
    float: left;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    font-size:125%;
}
#nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:0;
}

#nav li {
    float:left;
}

#nav li a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:17.5px 15px 17.5px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #438181; 
}

#nav li a:hover {
    color:#438181;
    background-color:#fff; 
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is by changing the list-items to `inline-block` instead of floating them, and then apply `text-align` center on the block container, the `<ul>` - e.g.

```
#nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:0;
    text-align: center;
}

#nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/suZR3/11/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `relative` positioning on the `ul` and `li` items.  First position the `ul` 50% to the left.  Then, as long as the `li` only take up the space they need (non block), have the move back to the right 50% of their width.

http://jsfiddle.net/suZR3/6/

```css
#nav ul {
     position: relative;
     left: 50%;
}
#nav li {
     position: relative;
     right: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the browser to calculate auto margins when the elements are floated, it needs widths.

```
#nav {
    background:#111212;
    height:55px;
    padding:0;
    font-size:125%;
}
#nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    width: 550px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:0;
}
```